# Error sending to my own email from Amazon SES

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ses

I keep getting an undelivered error when sending email to my own email address, but it works for other addresses. how do I even check what the error was? I cant seem to find an error log

Comment: Where do you see the error message that you describe? Can you post the log or screen shot of the actual undelivered message?

Comment: I'm getting an message from MAILER-DAEMON@amazonses.com
An error occurred while trying to deliver the mail to the following recipients:
myaddress.

Comment: There is usually more detail following that message. You would need to check that for root cause.